# Why hash_equals and password_verify are not working properly?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

In my log in page I am getting error after password_verify where as if I use hash_equals if verifies the password. Need to know the reason.

second problem is every time I change password through change password page hash_equals do not verify the password. below are the codes

```
if (!password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
    $errors[]='Password does not match';
}

if (!hash_equals($password, $user['password'])) {
    $errors[]='Password does not match';
}
```

Comment: Did you read the manual about these two functions at all?

Answer (score 0):

The function hash_equals() is not meant to verify a password with a hash, that's the job of the password_verify() function, so don't use hash_equals() in your code:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST['password'], $existingHashFromDb);
```